# Hosting service for audio/music social website

Tags: php, audio, download, hosting, soundcloud

Im building a music social network on zend framework 2.You can just imagine it as it was the same as SoundCloud, users upload songs, other users play them, those are the basic actions on the site.

I know that the server that will host the page will need a lot of bandwidth and disk space to host my site ( i think its a good idea to store the mp3 files on the server that hosts the page. am i wrong? ).

My two options are:
Setting my own server at home (core i7) and hiring an internet service with 10Mbps upload, 30Mbps download. (Maximum upload rate where i live)

Hosting the page in a "conventional" server, and pay the month fee.
I came across with Hostgator, i think is a good option (and cheap).
http://www.hostgator.com/promo/special-offer
Is that service the service i need? I mean, i think is too good to be true, 4 dollars per month, all the bandwidth and all the disk space i want. What about the computing power for processing all the php that my site requires?

Can anyone give me some advice? (Im a newbie web developer)

Comment: Neither is a good idea. Host your MP3s on a file storage system like Amazon S3, for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hostgator would definitely be able to run your website (providing it has the support for your chosen language and database e.g. PHP and MySQL). Beware though that some shared hosts such as this may have performance issues or some bandwidth restrictions (I don't have experience with Hostgator specifically though).

For the audio content, you will want to use some sort of CDN (content delivery network) to achieve the speed you will need to stream the music. An example is Amazon Cloudfront. Using a CDN for content will also take some load off your web server.

It is hard to recommend specifics for your particular case without knowing how much traffic you will be expecting, size and quality of audio files etc.

EDIT: Regarding the comments below, I should have been clearer in saying that although these hosting solutions can have performance issues, the price is usually very low. You could always start out with a service like Hostgator and then move to something better like Amazon AWS or Microsoft Azure in the future when the site starts to take off a bit.

Comment: I really dont know how much traffic to expect. I guess at the beggining the traffic will be very very low, and later (if i have some luck and the website becomes successful) it will grow. my ambition is to have a really big site in the future, so the solution must have to be able to scale correctly for a large amount of traffic/users uploads and downloads.

I didnt decide the quality of the mp3 files, i think converting them to 128kbps is a good idea. So, that the average mp3 file size will be 4 or 5 MB.

Comment: This answer says "would definitely be able to run your website" and then mentions performance issues / bandwidth restrictions that make it clear that you can't say that for certain at all. Odd.

Comment: I forgot to mention that these hosting solutions can be good to start off with as they are low cost, but the performance issues will definitely not work for a large site so when the site takes off, you would probably want to look for more costly but better performance solutions. Updated the answer to reflect that.